# Imperfect overlay Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, path, overlay

I'm trying to perfectly overlap two images, one complementary of the other, but apperas a white stripe in the conjunction of the path, all points are perfectly aligned how can I fix?

[image]

Comment: This is a rasterization error.  Theres not much you can do about this save use a different application. You can make the images overlap.

Comment: One thing you can do to avoid this is just Copy and paste another layer of both the objects. Try it I think it will solve your problem

Comment: [Some guys had been discussing a similar issue here](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/65058/image-looks-embossed-when-converted-to-svg) This may be helpful

Answer (score 1):

Well, just as joojaa said, this is a rasterization error, officialy there's not much that you can do about it but whenever I encounter this error, when the design and my time allows it I use the Direct Selection to select some points and the keyboard arrows to move them just a little to overlap the other image.

Another thing I do when I'm in a hurry, say for your design, Copy and Paste in place both objects, Unite them and send them to the back. See the difference:

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answers, I think i'll enlarge and move the path enough to cover up the error

Comment: @Ciuino You are welcome and good luck ;)

Answer (score 1):

One thing you can do to avoid this, is just **Copy and paste another layer of both the objects**. Try it I think it will solve your problem.