# How do I remove the outline in Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, logo

I just designed a logo for my own freelance business. It's funny that I don't know how to remove the lines of my own logo. I don't know how to describe the problem in English. Please see the picture below:

Ignore the "No selection" part. I made a mistake when posting this image. Also, if you can't see the line, open it in new tab and zoom in.

[image: The outline of the circles still visible even though i have set to transparent color, you may not see it unless you zoom in.]

Please note: I've tried using the Pathfinder but failed. I tried to ungroup all elements and do it again but it still failed. Help needed.

[image: Merge + Unite]

Comment: Please share file, so that I could help you

Comment: Currently the only way I could do is to use Print Screen key on my keyboard and Auto-Trace it in Illustrator while removing the background and refill the color. Though, this is a simple logo, I'm still looking for the **real** method to overcome this problem instead of "hack" tricks for the future. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You might want to include that commentary inside the question itself :)

Comment: @tolitt, I have found the solution in the answer section below, thanks for your offer :)

Comment: @ZachSaucier Done. :)

Comment: I only removed the word Answered. The green circle denotes an accepted answer. Nothing of the interior was edited by me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured it out only after I zoomed in your image, the border you are seeing isn't actually a border, it's a rasterization error found in Illustrator and there isn't much you can do about it. (see my answer on that topic [here](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/58826/48529)).

> Also, setting the opacity of an object to 0 won't make it disappear
>   and when you can still select it and see it's outline (the blue one).

In your case, trying to figure out an easy way for you to get the desired result is to:

1. Make all your shapes 100% opaque again and select all of them
2. Go to **Pathfinder** > **Divide**
3. Ungroup the resulting shape and delete all the other shapes not needed for your desired design
4. After you got your moustache design, select all the remaining shapes and go back to **Pathfinder** > **Unite** to unite all of them back into a single object.

[image]

### A very fast example of something looking like yours so you get my point:

[image]

This might not be the cleanest way of doing it or the fastest but it will get you there with little trouble since your design isn't that complicated.

Comment: I just did exactly how you said. It works. Couldn't ignore your hard work as well, I'm quite surprised how you eager to help me, even to redesign the logo itself. Don't know how can I repay your kindness. So... Love you. Have a wonderful life!

Comment: @AdamYoung It didn't take me that much time :) Don't mention it. If this answered your question, the one thing you can do is click the check mark next to my answer to mark this answer as correct :) Thank you and best of luck with your business!!

Comment: I voted your answer, thought that will be the way to make this answer as correct, but now i have click on the mark you mentioned best of luck to you as well :)

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to go about it

1. Using the path finder tool as described above. You can United different objects into one and you don't have to deal with individual objects anymore.
2. Using Shape Builder tool: Select the collection of objects. Hit Ctrl/Cmd + M, and thus you have selected the Shape Builder tool. Use the tool to run over (with left mouse click) the selection and you can build whatever shape you like.

Here is a tutorial if you want to read about it - https://helpx.adobe.com/illustrator/using/creating-shapes-shape-builder-tool.html

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answer as well as the link :)
I have use the first method.

Comment: Great! Maybe this will help you in future :)