# "Low quality edges" when importing 3d from illustrator to photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-illustrator, 3d

When I import a 3d vector from illustrator do photoshop, it looks like shapes get a tiny space between each other, besides the low quality appearence of the edges, as it can be seen on the picture below. [image: Notice the flaw between every shapes]

Does anyone know how to avoid it?

Comment: read: http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/73601/is-there-a-reason-hillarys-logo-has-hidden-notches and the linked answers. Use save for web with art optimized it does not have this problem

Comment: @joojaa that sounds like an answer ;)

Comment: @Cai in that case its a copy of http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/65058/image-looks-embossed-when-converted-to-svg

Comment: It's a rendering effect triggered by objects sharing an edge by either overlapping or touching. Try zooming in, you'll notice the "space" is gone.

Comment: This also sounds something like http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/58825/imperfect-overlay-illustrator/58826#58826

Answer (score 1):

Normally i see this issue occurring as an artifact from Photoshop when you cut or merge something that formerly had a gap inbetween them. As you save the file or look closer you will notice that the gaps aren't there anymore.

But i recall importing grouped shapes from illustrator and this thin gap was an actual issue, causing trouble even with layer styles. My solution there was to import the pieces separately and merging them in photoshop instead, but in your case it will take forever to import each piece of this.

Another way would be applying a very tiny offset path to it so it will overlap with each other, or filling a block of color behind it.